# Why is $(-\infty,1)$ the domain of the solution to $y'=y^2$, $y(0)=1$ instead of $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$y'=y^2$$ with initial condition $$y(0)=1$$.

A solution is $$y(t)=\frac{-1}{t-1}$$

Which the text I'm reading mentions is only valid on $(-\infty,1)$, which includes the left branch of the graph of this hyperbola. They justify this by saying that the initial condition is included in the left-hand side of the graph of this function, so that we cannot extend the solution to the entire real line. My question is, what is wrong with saying that the solution is $y(t)$ on $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,\infty)$? Why can we not include the rest of the domain where the solution $y(t)$ is defined? Thanks

EDIT: They mention that this is the "maximum interval on which the solution curve is defined", perhaps by calling it a solution "curve" they are implicitly trying to say we want the greatest domain on which the solution is continuous?

Comment: You can say that $y(x)$ satisfty $y' = y^2$ on the domain you suggest. The problem is that the ODE comes with an initial condition and one cannot propagate the solution from $t=0$ with $y(0) = 1$ past the singularity at $t=1$. That's why it doesn't make sense to say that *$y' = y^2$ with $y(0) = 1$* has the given solution for $t>1$.

Comment: @Winther By 'propagate', do you mean that if you were to move in space from left to right on the curve you would never reach the right-hand side of the branch? 

I've ran into many issues like this in this textbook and I'm thinking it's because in the back of their minds they have physical contexts where this is how you would interpret the solution, whereas from a strictly mathematical perspective it seems arbitrary to cut off the domain unless you want to maintain continuity/differentiability or some other property, say maybe the connectedness of the domain.

Comment: @Winther can one move to, say, assuming lipschitz continuity?

Comment: You certainly can say it is a solution. But you cannot say it is the solution. As Winther has pointed out in his comment above you lose uniqueness when going past the singularity. You could for example extend your solution by setting it identically zero to the right of the singularity, this would be a solution as well.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ah, it's the uniqueness. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Math-fun If you assume your vector field to be lipschitz continuous, then no such singularity will appear (i.e. you will have no blow-up in finite time). Thus, you get a unique global solution (this is the so-called Picard-Lindelöf theorem).

Comment: Maybe it sould be even better to say the domain is $\mathbb C \setminus \{1\}$.  In that sense, it is unique...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, actually, on the "universal" domain you are working in.  With real variables only, as others  ( notably @Severin Schraven) have explained you cannot determine the solutions uniquely past the singularity $x=1$.  You are blocked.  But in complex variables you can propagate around the pole and define the solution everywhere around said pole.  Then the solution $f(z)=-1/(z-1)$, using nomenclature usual for complex analysis, has as domain all complex inputs except $1$.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: @Severin Schraven added a direct reference, also +1 for your answer which is relevant in the real domain.  As you probably know, in the complex variables your "spliced" solution would have to miss the differential equation somewhere other than the pole.

Answer (score 5):

You certainly can say it is a solution. But you cannot say it is the solution. As Winther has pointed out in his comment above you lose uniqueness when going past the singularity. You could for example extend your solution by setting it identically zero to the right of the singularity, this would be a solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was conflicted but I ended up accepting the other one because I liked the discussion about complex numbers.

Comment: That has been a good choice. The other answer caputures the bigger picture :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, consider the domain where the solution is Lipschitz. If a function is not globally Lipschitz, then your ODE won't have a unique solution. This comes straight from the Picard-Lindelof theorem.

Comment: Acutally one needs to be careful. If the vector field is globally lipschitz, then by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem we get a unique global solution. However, the lipschitz condition is not necessary to get a unique global solution.